# Stop(Return) code from child method in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 project. And I want stop code from child method. For example in below example, if `studentNo` greater than 15 then I don't want run `alert("studentAge")`. In other words, I want to stop code from `calculate` method. How can I achieve this?

```
doSomething(studentAge){
 this.calculate(studentAge);

 alert(studentAge);
}

calculate(studentAge){
  if(studentAge > 15){ return; }
  else{ studentAge += 20 }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Start by making it compile so that it makes sense, and we can understand your question. I guess you want to actually return a value from calculate, and then use that returned value to check if alert should be called. But it's just a guess. This has nothing to do with Angular, BTW.

Comment: adding to what @JBNizet, cant see any declared variable `studentAge`. Provide a proper code. You can return `true` `false` as return of `calculate()` and put some conditional flag

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript passes arguments by **value**.

Modifying `studentAge` inside `calculate()` won't modify its value in `doSomething()`, because what `calculate()` receives is the **value** of `studentAge`. This method thus doesn't do anything.

Here's what I guess you actually want to do:

```
doSomething(studentAge: number) {
  studentAge = this.calculate(studentAge);
  if (studentAge <= 15) {
    alert(studentAge);
  }
}

calculate(studentAge: number): number {
  if (studentAge > 15) { 
    return studentAge; 
  }
  else { 
    return studentAge + 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this method easily same job. But I want stop from inner child method. Because, in my real scenario, calculate method is my helper method and calling from everywhere and there is a lot of `if`. But, I don't want use `if` in my `doSomething`methot. This is my main aim. @JBNizet

Comment: Other than by throwing an exception, you can't stop doSomething() to keep executing from the calculate() method.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that, it is possible. But,I understood from your reply that it is impossible.